# java socket listen without accepting the connection?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm new to Java, but not new to programming; I've been around computers since the days of DOS.

I'm trying to write a simple network proxy, and I want to listen for incoming connection requests, but I don't want to accept the request just yet as the client will then immediately send data. I want the proxy to attempt to successfully open a connection to the pre-configured destination before accepting the connection, and drop the connection if the destination cannot be reached.

This was possible in VB6 way back when, and I believe it's possible to do it in C# using events, but the problem is that the proxy machine is unix and I just don't feel masochistic enough to write anything in C++ just for one system.

anyone got any ideas on how to do this, or at least a kludge to simulate such a thing?
the article I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800960/java-socket-listen-before-accept) is too vague, and seems to be outdated as oracle docs seem to redirect to a different page.

Comment: The client can send data anyway before you accept the connection. Lots of it, up to the size of your socket receive buffer. Your question is based on a false premiss.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This isn't possible in Java. The way the socket libraries are written you cannot get details about an incoming connection without accepting it.

The link you provided would only help in rejecting connections before accepting them but I don't think it would allow you to use a connection the SecurityManager rejected.

Would it be possible to open the connection to the destination before accepting a connection, so then you only accept while you have a connection open to the destination?

Comment: the target server will drop that connection if no data is received after a set amount of time, so I can't preemptively open a connection.

Comment: I could accept the connection and then attempt to connect to the destination server, but I'm not sure how to handle the client if the destination can't be connected to. I suppose a simple socket close would be sufficient, but the client might freak out.

Comment: How will the server know what to connect to? And why should the client provide a listening socket? And an open firewall port? Answer doesn't make much sense. Not that the question does either.

Comment: I was assuming the destination was fixed, no matter the connection. Then you could be guaranteed that when you accept you can forward it on. However I do agree that the question seems a little odd.

Comment: So you're assuming there is only one client. Not exactly the normal case.

Comment: I never said you can't accept one client, create a Thread to handle it, then prepare a new socket and start listening again